# How do I make Firefox use the new (local) version of Java?

Tags: firefox, java, environment-variables, libraries

I'm kind of new to Java. I already had it downloaded but it needed to be updated. I updated it locally (without root), but Firefox is still using the old one from root.

How do I make it use the newer version? Preferably without root access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Find where the new `libpjp.so` is installed from your new java update. You can do

  ```
  find / -name "libpjp.so" 2>/dev/null
  ```

  and it will show you all the `libpjp.so` files on the filesystem.
- Create a plugins directory in your home directory's `~/.mozilla/` directory so you have `~/.mozilla/plugins`.
- Make a symlink in the plugins directory to the `libpjp.so` file and restart firefox.

[Source: Oracle.com](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/manual-plugin-install-linux-136395.html)

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me and now it uses the new version.